# How do you create a delegate based on a lambda using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, lambda, delegates

I have the following classes (I can't change them, they are not in my control):

```
public abstract class BusinessBase { }
public class A : BusinessBase { }
public class B : BusinessBase { }

public class FooOne
{
    public void Foo<T>(FooDelegates.Func<T> func) where T : BusinessBase { ... }
}

public class FooTwo
{
    public void Foo<T>(FooDelegates.Func<T> func) where T : BusinessBase { ... }
}

public static class FooDelegates
{
    public delegate TResult Func<TResult>();
}
```

Creating a delegate and calling the method is pretty straightforward:

```
var f1 = new FooOne();
f1.Foo(() => new A());
```

However, trying to use reflection to do this is proving to be a bit complicated. I have the following function which I cannot seem to finish:

```
public class GenericHelper
{
    // Parent can be A or B or etc...
    // Child is FooOne or FooTwo or etc...
    public void Relate(object parent, object child)
    {
        var mi = child.GetType().GetMethod("Foo");
        var gmi = mi.MakeGenericMethod(parent.GetType());

        // This next part obviously won't compile...
        var del = typeof(FooDelegates.Func<>).MakeGenericType(parent.GetType());
        FooDelegates.Func<parent.GetType()> del = () => parent;
        gmi.Invoke(child, new object[] { del });
    }
}
```

How do I correctly generate a `FooDelegates.Func<T>` where `T` is the parent type and I have an anonymous method as the assigned method?

Comment: You need to create and `Compile()` an expression tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use expression trees to compile new functions at runtime:

```
Expression.Lambda(del, Expression.Constant(parent)).Compile()
```

Comment: `del` is a `Type` for the delegate type.  You need to pass the compiled delegate _value_ from `Compile()`.

Comment: After correction and adjustments, it's very close. I get a different error though: `System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'Expression`1[...] cannot be converted to [...]`.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't call `Compile()`.